# Cereal versus Binary

Tags: haskell, serialization, deserialization

The two major competing packages for serializing and deserializing data in Haskell that I am aware of are binary and cereal.  When should one choose one of these packages over the other?  Or are there other choices that I am neglecting?

Answer (score 10):

They aren't competing, they are complementary.  `cereal` works on strict bytestrings while `binary` works on lazy.  Because of its lazy nature, `binary` depends on throwing an exception on parse error while `cereal` can fail via `Either`.

Also, to imply there are "only" two main packages is a misrepresentation.  At the very least you should look at blaze-builder too.

Comment: FYI cereal also works on lazy bytestrings.

Thanks for the note on blaze-builder, I'll check it out!

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure what the advantage of blaze-builder is, since it only offers capabilities for serializing (and not deserializing) data, and it doesn't have instances for anything but bytestrings and Storables.

Comment: Well if you only want to serialize then the lack of deserialization doesn't matter.  Also, blaze-builder is said to be much faster.  As for cereal working on lazy bytestrings, this is true but cereal is still strict in its operation (in order to return an error via `Either`).

Comment: By default, the binary package (post 0.5) reads the whole input, so any advantage due to lazy (i.e. streaming) processing requires extra effort.

Comment: Since September 2012 (since version 0.6) binary can also represent failure with a data type, not only by throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

For one thing, `binary` has [questionable default encoding](https://github.com/kolmodin/binary/issues/69) for floating point, instead of simply IEEE-754 encoding. So for example, NaN does not round-trip properly. `cereal` does not have such a known issue. The issue shows no sign of being resolved but can be circumvented by explicitly using things like `getFloatle`, which means generically derived instances of `Binary` still have the issue.

On the flip side, though, `binary` seems to be more popular than `cereal`. There are currently on hackage [345](https://packdeps.haskellers.com/reverse/cereal) packages that depend on `cereal` vs [821](https://packdeps.haskellers.com/reverse/binary) that depend on `binary`. So, you may find related libraries you need more easily if you choose `binary`.